# java program not running in intellij idea after i restart the intellij idea some internal call is showing up

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Internal error (java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException): Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1b1473ab
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1b1473ab
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:253)
at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:270)
at com.intellij.DynamicBundle.(DynamicBundle.java:28)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.InitialScalaBuilder.getPresentableName(InitialScalaBuilder.scala:26)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.lambda$sendElapsedTimeMessages$3(IncProjectBuilder.java:451)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3652)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.sendElapsedTimeMessages(IncProjectBuilder.java:454)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:425)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:132)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crXFB.png)

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attachd via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ Community version 2021.2 there might be some errors so I would recommend going back to the 2021.1 version.

These errors don't specifically look like an IDE error, but just in case I would recommend going back a version.